# Is it possible to build an Objective-C++ implementation from a C++ header?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4, objective-c++, grand-central-dispatch

I have a C++ framework I would like to use in Objective-C++.  I'm working in XCode4 and targeting an iPad deployment.

So given this (pseudocode) C++ header:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int doSomething(int i) = 0;
private:
    int _i;
}
```

For this specific instance, I need to have `doSomething` dispatch something via Grand Central Dispatch.

I'm having trouble finding solutions to implement C++ headers in Objective-C++.  Is it possible to do so?  If so, can somebody provide a great example?

Thanks!

Comment: I think in this thread they try exactly what you want: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=495324

Comment: Are you looking for automatic translation? Or by hand?

Comment: @Seva: Can you help me understand what you mean by "automatic translation"?  I simply want to keep the C++ header as-is and use it in Objective-C++.  Thanks!

Comment: Luckily, Grand Central Dispatch is a C library, so you don't even need Objective-C to use it, if I recall correctly. But even so, you could implement your class in a `.mm` if you wanted to, intermixing C++ and Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a C++ framework in Objective C++ as it is. Just include the .h files, and start instantiating classes.

To make sure your sources compile as ObjC++ as opposed to ObjC, make sure your sources have the .mm extension.

Objective C++ is a weird beast - it has two class/object systems running side by side. You can have C++ functions call ObjC methods, and vice versa. What you cannot do though, you cannot derive Objective C classes from C++ classes and vice versa.

I was under impression that you're looking to convert a C++ class library into an ObjC class library. That would be rather time-consuming.